# Change font size on button

Tags: .net, wpf

WPF on the form has a button when the button resizes the form changes the size. How would I change the font size on buttons when resizing the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in a TextBlock inside a ViewBox.

```
<Button>
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Then add some margins to the ViewBox.
You can adjust the Stretch and StretchDirection as required (i.e. do you want to text to be vertically stretched, or do you want the proportions to stay the same?). The default stretch is Uniform which is probably what you want.

Comment: I would not use Viewbox for fontsize changing. Some fonts come out blurry.

Comment: Looks fine to me (in .NET 4). It's a bit blurry while it's being resized, but then settles down nicely.